# Applying Dynamic texture in arcore 3D model

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

i am unable to apply texture on 3d model which is convert from google scene form plugin. 
i only able to add texture on "andy" model,
all custom models are not taking any texture.

i have tried to apply texture technique which i found on github here is the link where i found 
https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/41

```
    CompletableFuture<Texture> futuretexture= Texture.builder().setSource(this, R.drawable.texture).build();
    ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this, R.raw.model)
            .build()
            .thenAcceptBoth(futuretexture, (renderable, texture) -> {
                andyRenderable = renderable;
                andyRenderable.getMaterial().setTexture(MaterialFactory.MATERIAL_TEXTURE, texture);
            })
            .exceptionally(
                    throwable -> {
                        Toast toast =
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load model_node renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        return null;
                    });
```

i expected to have texture which we selected on button click is applied on projected 3d model in ar core android

Answer (score 2):

Not all models have a predefined texture sampler. So if you try to set a texture to a model wich doesn't have any texture channel you must first set a custom material to it.

When you convert you model to sfb via android studio you can specify a custom material file. Here a simple example of a material where you can set a custom texture:

```
material {
    name : "Textured material",
    parameters : [
        {
           type : sampler2d,
           name : texture
        }
    ],
    requires : [
        uv0
    ],
    shadingModel : lit,
    blending : opaque
}

fragment {
    void material(inout MaterialInputs material) {
        prepareMaterial(material);
        material.baseColor = texture(materialParams_texture, getUV0());
    }
}
```

Just save this as a .mat file, create the sfb with this material and then you code from above should work. If you want to apply the material at runtime it is not possible at moment without a small workaround. Just create a simple 3d model (for example a triangle) and convert it with this material to sfb. Then load the material at runtime and copy the material from it. Now when you load you model which you want to show you can simply override the original material with you custom one.

Comment: i have not find it useful even if i use this mat file still no texture has been added on model..

Comment: i am still unable to add texture thorough this technique also i am facing problem in model conversion to .sfb is there any work around for this or what i am doing wrong. Any help in this regard appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I built a texture completableFuture

```
val texture = Texture.builder()
                        .setSource(
                            requireContext(),
                            Uri.parse(filePath.absolutePath) //"assets.png"
                        )
                        .setUsage(Texture.Usage.DATA)
                        .setSampler(
                            Texture.Sampler.builder()
                                .setMagFilter(Texture.Sampler.MagFilter.LINEAR)
                                .setMinFilter(Texture.Sampler.MinFilter.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
                                .build()
                        ).build()
```

//inside achor, I tried initiating the model further

```
val anchor = hitResult.createAnchor()
        model?.thenAccept { modelRenderable ->
            addModelToScene(arFragment, anchor, modelRenderable)
            viewModel.modelRenderable = modelRenderable
        }
enter code here
```

Inside the addModelToScene I tried applying the texture to the loaded model.

```
 private fun addModelToScene(
        arFragment: ARFragment,
        anchor: Anchor?,
        modelRenderable: ModelRenderable?,
    ) {
        val anchorNode = anchor?.let { AnchorNode(it) }


arFragment.transformationSystem.selectionVisualizer =
            ARSupportHelper.Companion.HideCircleOnSelectionVisualiser()

        


val transformableNode =
            TransformableNode(arFragment.transformationSystem)

texture?.thenAccept { texture ->

            MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithTexture(requireContext(), texture)
                .thenAccept { material: Material? ->
                    // Apply the material to the model

                    // Set the texture as a diffuse map
                    material?.setFloat3(
                        MaterialFactory.MATERIAL_COLOR,
                        com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Color(0.219f, 0.172f, 0.52f)
                    )
                    material?.setTexture(MaterialFactory.MATERIAL_TEXTURE, texture)
                    transformableNode.renderable?.material = material
                }
                .exceptionally { throwable: Throwable ->
                    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
                    builder.setTitle("Material Load Err!")
                    builder.setMessage(throwable.message).show()
                    return@exceptionally null
                }
        }
```

There are multiple options like `makeOpaqueWithTexture`, `makeOpaqueWithColor`, `makeTransparentWithTexture`, `makeTransparentWithColor`